# How do I use a model after it's fitted to predict the class of a single string?

Tags: python, classification, keras, cnn, prediction

After a model is built, how can I use it to predict the class of a single string?

`model.predict()` is returning something like `[[0.41100174 0.5889983 ]]` instead of it's predicted class (`0` or `1`).

Say I just built `model` like so:

```
hist = model.fit(data.x_train,
                 data.y_train,
                 validation_data=(data.x_test, data.y_test),
                 epochs=500,
                 batch_size=50,
                 shuffle=False,
                 verbose=2,
                 callbacks=[checkpoint, estopping, tensorboard])
```

I'm looking to predict a string's class using `model.predict()`, but it returns something like `[[0.41100174 0.5889983 ]]` instead of it's predicted class (`0` or `1`).

The shape of `data.x_test` (used for validation data) is the same shape as `data.x_data` (reformatted string to predict): `(1, 250, 70)` (except the number of rows, obviously)

Here's how I'm trying to use the model to predict the class of a string.

```
def predict_string(model,s):
    df = pd.DataFrame([s], columns=['text'])
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    df['label'] = [0]

    df.label = pd.to_numeric(df.label, errors='coerce') # Convert to integer
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df[df.label.apply(lambda x: x !="")]
    df = df[df.text.apply(lambda x: x !="")]

    vocab_len = 70
    data = char_preproc(df.text, df.label, vocab_len, True, None)
    y_pred = model.predict(data.x_data)
    return y_pred


s = "Best movie ever" # Out: [[0.41100174 0.5889983 ]]

# s = "Worst movie ever" # Out: [[0.5436389  0.45636114]]

y_pred = predict_string(model, s)
print("Review: {}\"\nPredict: {}".format(s, y_pred))
```

I'm not sure it matters, but for testing, I'm classifying movie reviews as good (`1`) or bad (`0`) using a [Character-level CNN](https://github.com/puyash/text-classification) trained on the [Rotten Tomatoes Movie Review dataset](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/), running on GPU via Google Colab.

Comment: Those are the probabilities which your model thinks the given test image belongs to, you can use argmax(np.argmax())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[0.41100174 0.5889983 ]]` what this means is the probability of class 0 is 0.411 and probability of class 1 is 0.588. Since probability of class 1 is greater than probability of class 0, it belongs to class 1.

`a = [[0.41100174 0.5889983 ]]`

`np.argmax(a)`

`Output : 1`

`np.argmax` will get you the class.

Comment: FYI: `a = [[0.5  0.5 ]]; np.argmax(a)` returns `1`. Is there a numpy way to only return `1` if it's actually greater than the probability of the `0` class?